# php + mysql, order by name + starting at specific id

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

MySQL:

```
id | name  |
------------
1  | Joe   |
2  | Craig |
3  | Shawn |
4  | Ryan  |
5  | Seth  |
```

PHP:

```
$a = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY name DESC");
```

what I want to do though is, I want to start at **id: 3**, so it should output:

3,4,5,1,2

Comment: In what way are you "ordering by name" as in your title? It looks like you want to order by id.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT : Mark is correct. The earlier query was syntactically incorrect.
Using dummy aliasés should work!

```
Select id from
(
    SELECT id FROM table_name 
    WHERE id >= 3 
    ORDER BY id ASC
) X   

UNION

Select * from
(
    SELECT id FROM table_name 
    WHERE id < 3 
    ORDER BY id ASC
) Y
```

This should give you 3,4,5,1,2

Answer (score 13):

You can use an expression in the ORDER BY:

```
SELECT id, name
FROM table_name
ORDER BY id < 3, id
```

Result:

```
3  Shawn
4  Ryan
5  Seth
1  Joe
2  Craig
```

I'd also advise you not to use `SELECT *` and instead to list the columns explicitly.

Comment: +1 - This is a much cleaner way of achieving the same thing!! :-)