# MySQL Order from a starting value

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

On a product page I have a dropdown that lists current colour options associated to product page.

In this example, the product page SKU is 250E and it available in:

```
GREEN
BLACK
```

If the customer selects GREEN, then I want to run a MySQL command that will change the data to show GREEN values first based in the custom_order value shown below.

The start value should overide the other data items and then it should retain custom_order values. The custom_order field has letters like c1, c2 (they will always be at the bottom)

```
Colour Table
============
ID      COLOURID        NAME
-------------------------------------
2           5           BLACK
3           6           GREEN


Product Table
=============
ID      SKU         PICTURE URL             COLOURID            CUSTOM_ORDER        
-----------------------------------------------------------------
22      250E        cdn_hash_1.jpg          5                   1
23      250E        cdn_hash_2.jpg          5                   2
24      250E        cdn_hash_3.jpg          5                   3
225     250E        cdn_hash_4.jpg          5                   4
226     250E        cdn_hash_5.jpg          6                   5
227     250E        cdn_hash_6.jpg          6                   6
325     250E        cdn_hash_c1.jpg         -                   c1
426     250E        cdn_hash_c2.jpg         -                   c2
527     250E        cdn_hash_c3.jpg         -                   c3
```

**SELECT * FROM products WHERE ORDER BY custom_order DESC**

Now, I want to do the following:

**SELECT * FROM products WHERE ORDER BY custom_order AND START VALUE = '6'**

Therefore, no matter what, the c1, c2 remain intact, result would be:

```
22      250E        cdn_hash_5.jpg          6                   5
23      250E        cdn_hash_6.jpg          6                   6
24      250E        cdn_hash_1.jpg          5                   1
225     250E        cdn_hash_2.jpg          5                   2
226     250E        cdn_hash_3.jpg          5                   3
227     250E        cdn_hash_4.jpg          5                   4
325     250E        cdn_hash_c1.jpg         -                   c1
426     250E        cdn_hash_c2.jpg         -                   c2
527     250E        cdn_hash_c3.jpg         -                   c3
```

Comment: it would be wise to rename your `order` column. `ORDER` is a reserved word in mysql.

Comment: Judging from the answers, I think you need to clarify the sort order. Should `START_VALUE` apply to the `COLOURID` to place entries with that ID first (sorted by `CUSTOM_ORDER`) and then sort the remaining entries using only `CUSTOM_ORDER`?

Comment: Yes. Exactly I have updated the question a bit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the answer I was looking for. I hope I am not downvoted for this but I managed to resolve this.

Let me explain again simpler terms. MySQL ORDER BY + Start with..

```
MySQL:

id | name  |
------------
1  | Joe   |
2  | Craig |
3  | Shawn |
4  | Ryan  |
5  | Seth  |
```

PHP:

```
$a = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY name DESC");
```

what I want to do though is, I want to start at id: 3, so it should output:

```
3,4,5,1,2
```

## Solution 1

```
SELECT id, name
FROM table_name
ORDER BY id < 3, id
```

Result:

```
3  Shawn
4  Ryan
5  Seth
1  Joe
2  Craig
```

## Solution 2

You can use `FIELD`, eg

```
SELECT * 
FROM products 
ORDER BY FIELD(`order`, 6) ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

`WHERE` condition should come before `ORDER BY` clause

```
SELECT * 
FROM products 
WHERE START_VALUE = '6' 
ORDER BY order
```

As a sidenote, `ORDER` is a `RESERVED` keyword. One way to escape it is by wrapping with backtick. eg,

```
SELECT * 
FROM products 
WHERE START_VALUE = '6' 
ORDER BY `order`
```

Another is by supplying an `ALIAS`

```
SELECT * 
FROM products p
WHERE START_VALUE = '6' 
ORDER BY p.order
```

but looking back at your question, you want to custom order the data right? You can use `FIELD`, eg

```
SELECT * 
FROM products 
ORDER BY FIELD(`order`, 6) ASC
```

Comment: Why did you remove `START VALUE`

Comment: i can't see `START VALUE` in your columns. Do you want to custom the order right? the first one should start on the list should have a value of `6`?

Comment: I liked your previous answer. Yes, if a customer chooses a colour from the form field on the page. The dropdown value is 6 or 30 - whatever, then it should start with that group first..

Comment: i just rollback the answer, which of them should I unstrike?

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid that's why i strike them. how about using `FIELD`?

Comment: FIELD solution worked. I have marked this as an answer via upvote I went for the `<` command as reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797671/php-mysql-order-by-name-starting-at-specific-id

Answer (score -2):

please clear your question. if you want all records, use query like below...

SELECT * FROM products WHERE ORDER BY COLOURID ASC, order DESC

Comment: ...and where's the start value taken into account?