# Custom order by query

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to customize ORDER BY query in MySQL ?

I have test table that contains id and time like this:

[image]

I then use query like this:

```
SELECT time FROM `test` ORDER BY time ASC
```

Then its sorts time in logical way:

[image]

But is it possible to customize order by query, so it would sort from my test table by time, but would start at 05:00 and ends with 02:30 ?

Desired ordering:

[image]

To explain more, i am making an daily work plan, but my workday starts at 05:00 and ends in 02:30 on next day, thats why i want to order it this way.

Is it possible to do this, or its better to rearrange things in php array somehow ?

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14358656/mysql-order-from-a-starting-value

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use two keys:

```
order by (time >= '05:00:00') desc,
         time
```

Answer (score 0):

You Have to Use Case in Order by Like Below I did

ORDER BY (CASE WHEN `time`>='05:00' THEN '0' ELSE `time` END) ASC